# Make Ant Design Modal Confirm Cancel Button disable immediately after clicking Ok Button

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

the

```
confirm({
  cancelButtonProps: {
    disabled: this.state.processing
  },
  onOk: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.setState({
        processing: true
      })
    })
  }
})
```

doesnt really work cos it doesnt pick the update in the state immediately. It only works after you click on the cancel button and reinitiate the modal confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the disabled that comes with the

```
cancelButtonProps
```

just use this rather

```
confirm({
  cancelButtonProps: {
    onClick: () => {
      if (this.state.processing) {
        alert('You cant cancel, processing still un-going')
      } else {
        Modal.destroyAll() //use Modal.destroyAll() to destroy the confirm modal
      }
    }
  },
  onOk: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.setState({
        processing: true
      })
    })
  }
})
```